# Auto Scroll is not working in react even after adding eventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autoscroll

I am trying to create a chat application, whenever a new message is sent, so it should auto scroll..

But it's not working for me.
I have added an event listener to `chatBox`, i did console.log inside the event callback even it was not working..

I also tried like before event listener, console.log(chatBox.container) i was getting the div in the console

Here's Code :

basically, i have tried this
but it's not auto scrolling

```
const chatBox = useRef(null); // stores the refrence of any component inside a variable
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(chatBox.current);
    chatBox.current.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", (event) => {
      const { currentTarget: target } = event;
      target.scroll({ top: target.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });
    });
  }, [chatMessages]);
```

my div :

```
 <div className="chat-container-header-btn" ref={chatBox}>
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </div>
```

I tried this as well from an articl :

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    chatBox.current?.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "end",
      inline: "nearest",
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollToBottom();
  }, [chatMessages]);
```

Comment: try adding `chatBox` as a dependency to the last code.

Comment: I didn't get you can you elaborate?

Comment: `useEffect(() => { scrollToBottom(); }, [chatMessages, chatBox]);`

Comment: I have tried but its not working as well

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways and this is the only one that managed to auto-scroll a div as its content expands:

**Step 1:** Import the necessary references

```js
   import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
```

**Step 2:** Inside your function component, declare your ref constant

```js
   const refDivAfterMessages = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

**Step 3:** Inside your div container, and after its content, add a new DIV and add to it the ref you declared in the previous step:

```js
   <div ref={refDivAfterMessages} />
```

**Step 4:** Define your useEffect and set it's DependencyList to your list length, using the scrollIntoView to give the scroll attributes:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.messages.length) {
      refDivAfterMessages.current?.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "end",
      });
    }
  }, [props.messages.length]);
```

Credits to Source: https://reacthustle.com/blog/react-auto-scroll-to-bottom-tutorial